# VB solution runs in debugger but not with exe's in bin folder

Tags: vb.net, windows, debugging

I have a solution that use external dll's in vb, which works perfectly when I run it from vb in debugger. However when trying to execute the program from the exe files in the bin folder the program crashes with the release exe giving a "InvalidOperation" message and the debug exe gives the error message shown below.

[image: Debug exe error]

The code segments are:

**vb:**

```
<DllImport("libjcom_exp-0.dll", Entrypoint:="jcreate")> _
Public Shared Function Jcreate() As IntPtr
End Function

Public Sub New()
    objptr = Jcreate()
    error_message = Jget_last_err(objptr)
    Jset_rps(objptr, 40)
    If error_message.Length <> 0 Then
        Throw New System.Exception(error_message)
    End If
End Sub
```

**c++:**

```cpp
DLL_EXP void * __stdcall jcreate()
{
  return new libjcom_exp; 
}
```

Things that I have tried from searching around:

- Disable anti virus
- Compile without optimizations
- Use dependency walker to check if all dll's are included in the bin folder
- Confirm that the exe and all related files builds into the correct folder
- Project is build as a x86 project

Someone else suggested that the 'jcreate' and 'get_last_error' functions executes at the same time where in the debug mode you individually step over single lines, which then does not trigger the problem.

The OS is Windows 10 and VB 2008.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I also used 'Run as administrator' on both exe's with the same result

Comment: You could add a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` between jcreate and get_last_error and check if the problem still occurs. If not, the suggestion seems to be correct.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very nice first question! Such well-formatted, short, and concise first questions are rare these days! (I just changed some minor things to improve the code's readability) -- Now, to your problem. I believe `DLL_EXP` is a macro for `__declspec(dllexport)`, correct? Is your code wrapped in an `extern "C" {...}` block? If not, try to do so and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: P.S: Also make sure you have the C++ dll in the same folder as the .exe.

Comment: Hi guys sorry for the late response. @Alex B. I tried adding the 1sec delay between the functions, with no difference in the response. Vincent That is correct, all the functions are also wrapped in a extern "C" block. The build directory also contain all the necessary dll's.

Comment: EDIT: I removed the initial get_last_error function that is called when the class is created, which resulted that the exe will execute. Does this then mean that the pointer that jcreate() generates is only valid after the entire execution of the New()  process?